# Errno 2 No such file or directory: 'utils\\expiry_list.csv'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Error while runnind boot3 and then getting data.
expiries = get_data('options', 'BANKNIFTY', custom="select DISTINCT(expiry) from "spot_backtesting_data";")
expiries.to_csv('utils\expiry_list.csv', index=False)

to save files in my local in csv datewise

Comment: An app running on AWS is not connected to your local disk.  You would have to save the file to the AWS instance and then fetch it after.

Comment: Format code...Can't even understand that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you not sure why path is not detectable you can create a dummy own directory and save the output later you can search with folder name.

> Note: format your code...I can't understand anything...So i'm just
> left that portion as #your code

```
from pathlib import Path

output_file = 'expiry_list.csv'
output_dir = Path('Nikil_csv/utils')

output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

#your code
#your code
#your code

custom="select DISTINCT(expiry) 
from "spot_backtesting_data";")expiries.to_csv(output_dir / output_file, index=False)
```

your csv file will be at `Nikil_csv/utils/expiry_list.csv`